# Restricting the assumptions of a role on a per region basis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I was reading an article on the AWS blog about restricting permissions on a per region basis -  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easier-way-to-control-access-to-aws-regions-using-iam-policies/.

I have the following setup - Account A and account B.

Account A has a collection of DynamoDB global tables in multiple regions. 
Account B basically assumes a role in account A to gain access to these DynamoDB tables.

In order to have region based separation, I have IAM roles in accountA in the format crossAccountTrustedRole-. The flow is such that, accountB when operating in us-east-1, it assumes the role with name crossAccountTrustedRole-us-east-1 and accesses the data.

Now in the assumeRole policy document, I have the trusted entity to be the entire account itself. I didn't want to specifically go into the pain of scoping it down to a role. I want safety such that accountB in region us-west-2 cannot assume a role of the name crossAccountTrustedRole-us-east-1 in accountA. Reading that article made me think its technically possible to do that right now. I was thinking I could write an IAM policy which restricts the assumeRole API call to have the requested region to be the same region as the incoming request.

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"aws:RequestedRegion": "eu-central-1"}
}
```

Is this possible? Or has anybody given this a shot previously?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What makes you feel doubtful about it?

Comment: IAM roles aren't regionalized whatsoever and are global. So I wasn't sure if that was applicable in this case or not.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking I could write an IAM policy which restricts the
>   assumeRole API call to have the requested region to be the same region
>   as the incoming request.

No, you cannot apply an IAM policy to a user / group based upon region - IAM users do not have a region. You can apply an IAM policy based upon region to resources. A resource such as Lambda, S3, EC2, etc.

The purpose of the region condition is to prevent or control where resource are created / managed. You could prevent a user from creating resources in the US, prevent a user from deleting resources in Europe, etc.

Comment: This isn't exactly similar, but can we not restrict the assumeRole call happening based on setting the "aws:RequestedRegion" context key?